# Automatically create class in Eclipse with Pydev

Tags: python, eclipse, tdd, pydev

I am developing a python system with Eclipse and Pydev using TDD. When I write the code for the tests, the IDE shows erros in classes in methods since I have not writen the code. Can I do the IDE creates the classes with the methods automatically while I write the code?

Comment: This is not Smalltalk.

Comment: @quamrana What is that supposed to mean?

Comment: Yes, if you were writing in Smalltalk and you run the code, you get exceptions for missing classes and methods and the IDE suspends the program and can be made to write skeleton code and you can fill in the method and continue running the program without having to restart. But still, if you're talking about Python, pydev/Eclipse or PyCharm can 'correct' these things at code writing time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible...

When the error is highlighted use `Ctrl+1` and choose the option to create the class. The following video shows how this is done: http://www.pydev.org/video_pydev_20.html